# See t-s and t-v graphs of motion tracking points

Tags: graph-editor, motion-capture

Is it possible to display the movement of the tracking points of Blender's motion tracking function as a graph (probably in the graph view tab) with time[seconds or current frame] on the x-axis and either distance covered or velocity on the y-axis?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you get on the right track (the idea is to bake the tracked object's motion to an animation curve): [Getting raw data from object track](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23218/getting-raw-data-from-object-track?rq=1)

You may need to write some python at some point, depending on the information you want to get out.

Edit to add more info quoted from the linked answer:

> You can use a Follow Track constraint to 'project' a single track onto an object.
>
> 1. track your point, you dont need to solve the camera.
> 2. make a plane, and position it perpendicular to the camera... how you want to set this up is up to you, but it will effect the numbers you get out at the end.
> 3. add the constraint to an object, i just used the default Cube, and refer to the image bellow on how i set it up.
> 4. in the viewport image, I have calculated the motion paths, and you can see the path of the track is on the plane.
> 5. click the Constraint to Fcurve button, and it will bake the constraint to XYZ values. Edit: Some times this button doesn't work. An alternative is: Search->Bake Action
> 6. you can then write some python to convert your animation to CSV format.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped me to move on. The only problem is now, that I can not get the right unit (m or cm) and I do not see any possibility to define a given length in the video to be xyz Meters.